# Почему не получается вывести двумерный массив?

Tags: c++, массивы

Возможно ли пройтись по всем элементам двумерного массива array в одном цикле?
В теории все элементы массива в памяти идут подряд, но на практике на этапе выполнения появляется ошибка при переходе к новой строке

```
std::array<std::array<int, SIZE>, SIZE> mas;    
for (auto i = mas.front().begin();i< mas.back().end();++i)
        std::cout << *i<< std::endl;
```

Comment: Они не подряд идут, многомерный массив - это массив указателей. А уж с контейнерами в таком ключе вы напрасно экспериментируете.

Comment: В C++ нет двумерных массивов. Если хотите расположить элементы подряд, то почему изначально это не сделать (`std::array<int, SIZE*SIZE>`)?

Comment: @dIm0n, в смысле нет? А это что `int array[rows][cols];`?

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον массив указателей

Comment: @dIm0n, масло масленое =) Это одно и то же

Comment: @dIm0n это не массив указателей, это массив, элементами которого являются другие массивы

Comment: @user7860670 согласен, просто если говорить указатели, то понятней, что имеется в виду под "одномерный"

Comment: @user7860670, внутренне - это все равно массив указателей, вы можете это проверить таким образом: `*(*(array + row) + col)`.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Это не массив указателей. И вложенный `std::array` - тоже не массив указателей. Ваша запись работает потому, что массив автоматически преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ясное дело, что контейнер - не массив указателей. Я этого и не утверждал.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον *"Я этого и не утверждал."* ... *"Они не подряд идут, многомерный массив - это массив указателей"* 

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον вас случаем не вводит в заблуждение неявное преобразование массивов в указатель на первый элемент?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я про `std::array`, это контейнер, а не массив. Речь не о нём.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Еще раз. Вы первым комментарием сказали, что подмассивы "идут не подряд". Это не так.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я когда то давно экспериментировал, и это так. У меня не получилось получить доступ иначе.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Вот: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/K8jzh1 Адреса соседних массивов отличаются ровно на размер этих самых массивов.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Многомерные массивы (не `array`) в С++ лежат подряд, одним блоком в памяти. Доступ к ним можно получить и так, как описали вы - но это не значит, что где-то в этом блоке лежат указатели!! Их там нет, это - вычисление "на лету". Массива указателей при этом нет! (хотя можно использовать структуру с массивом указателей, создавая ее вручную, которая будет работать внешне так же, но это будет совсем другая история...)

Comment: Ок, я был неправ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А **как** это может работать? Вы сравниваете итераторы из двух совершенно разных массивов...

Действуйте примерно так:

```
for (auto m2: mas)
    for (auto i: mas2)
        std::cout << i<< std::endl;
```